# Text files vs MySQL. Which is better for storing wiki information

Tags: mysql, wiki

I have been storing my wiki information in a MySQL database. However, it seems like kind of a waste to store huge amounts of info in a relational database. I am thinking of moving the bulk of the information to text files. Does anyone have experience with which would be better?

Comment: If it is only for personal use, and it won`t change frequently - maybe. In any othe case is better to use database.

Comment: What's the waste? If it is text it won't get more than a few Gig, right?

Comment: Well, perhaps waste is the wrong word. I just seems like most wiki information isn't actually relational in nature. Most wiki pages seem like they are just a huge lump of information that is displayed all at once. Yes, you can edit individual parts but those parts aren't really processed individually or related to other things, they are just displayed en masse, all at once. To that end, I was wondering if the bulk of each wiki post would be better stored in a text file. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want do that,

if you do that, how you can perform search on your wiki?

a wiki post should be processed to build blue links and red links, how you want do that in text file?

after processing wiki post it's good to cache it in text file, we have a large wiki and store processed wiki in another table, its very fast.

Comment: We process each wiki submission for key words and store those in a database (which is used for searching). However, the submission itself could potentially be stored in a text file, to avoid creating a huge database file. 
Can you explain what you mean about storing "processed wiki in another table". When do you consider part of the wiki processed?
Thanks for you help.

Comment: I think there is some rules about wiki, insert image, link, other html tags by predefined symbols such as {{topic}}, link to another wiki that not created yet, this link will be in red color and ...